# How can I get friends pictore using by android-simple-facebook libraries

Tags: android-simple-facebook

I'm using latest android-simple-facebook library 
(https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook)
and, want to get friends list with name, picture(profile image).

but i cann't get friends picture at all..

below is my code...

At LoginListener

```
private OnLoginListener mOnLoginListener = new OnLoginListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFail(String reason) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to login");
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onThinking() {
        // show progress bar or something to the user while login is
        // happening
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogin() {
        PictureAttributes pictureAttributes = Attributes.createPictureAttributes();
        pictureAttributes.setType(PictureType.NORMAL);
        pictureAttributes.setHeight(500);
        pictureAttributes.setWidth(500);

        // change the state of the button or do whatever you want
        Properties properties = new Properties.Builder()
                .add(Properties.ID)
                .add(Properties.LAST_NAME)
                .add(Properties.PICTURE, pictureAttributes)
                .add(Properties.BIRTHDAY).build();

        mSimpleFacebook.getFriends(properties, mOnFriendsListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotAcceptingPermissions(Permission.Type type) {
    }
};
```

and the friends listener

```
    // get friends listener
private OnFriendsListener mOnFriendsListener = new OnFriendsListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFail(String reason) {
        // insure that you are logged in before getting the friends
        Log.w(TAG, reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onThinking() {
        // show progress bar or something to the user while fetching profile
        Log.i(TAG, "Thinking...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {
        for (Profile profile : friends) {
            mLists.add(new FriendItem(profile.getName(), profile.getPicture()));                
        }
        mAdapter = new FriendsListAdapter(getActivity());
        mFriendsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

};
```

but the profile object only contains id and name.
should i call get method with async?
or whatever else i can do with getFriends() methods.

The permission lists is likes:

```
        Permission[] permissions = new Permission[] { 
            Permission.BASIC_INFO, 
            Permission.USER_CHECKINS, 
            Permission.USER_EVENTS, 
            Permission.USER_GROUPS, 
            Permission.USER_LIKES, 
            Permission.USER_PHOTOS,
            Permission.USER_VIDEOS, 
            Permission.FRIENDS_EVENTS, 
            Permission.FRIENDS_PHOTOS,
            Permission.PUBLISH_STREAM };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you have to override onComplete() method inside onLogin to handle with the things that you asked for.

Response will have everything that you asked for in the permissions builder.

I spent a huge amount of time to figure out this. Hope it helps :)

```
final OnLoginListener onLoginListener = new OnLoginListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLogin(String accessToken, List<Permission> acceptedPermissions, List<Permission> declinedPermissions) {
                OnProfileListener onProfileListener = new OnProfileListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(final Profile response) {
                        super.onComplete(response);
                        .
                        . // Your code in here`enter code here`
                        .
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz try these permissions:
  Permission.PUBLIC_PROFILE,
  Permission.USER_BIRTHDAY